# Is this reasonable privacy for storing sensitive information?

Tags: encryption, web-application, privacy, key-management

**Outline**

I am writing a web app that will need to store some transaction data (amount, date, merchant...).

**Objective**

I want to keep this data reasonably private from unwelcome eyes.

**Threat Model**

I don't anticipate anything huge. The audience is pretty small (~200 for now), and the data is not bank account/credit card info.

**Current Design**

There are three components to the app: Identity/auth server, api/database backend, web app front end.

1. Upon registration, a cryptograhically random string is generated as a key for the user and stored on the identity/auth server.
2. After the user is logged in (OpenId Connect), the key is passed from the auth server to the api/database backend in the access token. The token is then encrypted and sent to the web app as a cookie.
3. User sends data to store -> backend decrypts token and gets key ->
   backend uses key to encrypt data and then stores it in the database.
4. User requests data to read -> backend decrypts token and gets key -> backend fetches data by user id -> backend uses key from earlier to decrypt key and send to web app.

All communication occurs over TLS

**Attack Vectors**

1. Identity/Auth server compromised: Attacker can get data by logging in on web app with credentials taken from server.
2. The api/database backend is compromised: Attacker can't get anything because data is encrypted, and not user identity info is stored here.
3. Web app is compromised from the user end. All data can now be accessed as long as user is still logged in.

**Questions**

1. Does this seem reasonable?
2. Is there a glaring loophole that my dumb brain can't think of?
3. Is there a better/standard way of encrypting data when using an identity/auth server?

Any help/thoughts would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I think it may be helpful to the question, and for your reference, to reframe the section about attack vectors with the [OWASP Top Ten](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) risks. Your risks are not necessarily binary: compromised or un-compromised. A lot of attacks do not require the attacker to "gain access" or "compromise" an application, they can get things by simply misusing/abusing the application or its users

Comment: I will go take a look, thank you for the resource!